# How to deploy two WAR File over Weblogic Application Server and Execute Both Simaltaneously

Tags: java, weblogic

Hi  I Want to deploy two copies of same java web application over Weblogic Application Server with some little changes.but i am not getting how to deploy two war file of application  over server,and use it simaltaneously..plz help me out..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you have to use different context-root in weblogic.xml

[Please see](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1073750)

Comment: hi sanjay,Thanx for reply but i am unable to understand document u have attached.can u give me some example.i want to run two application war file simaltaneously over server..

Comment: i am working in eclipse. and there is no Weblogic.xml file in my project,should i create a new one??

Comment: Check under WebContent/WEB-INF folder. if it is not there then check web.xml to find out the current context defined in form of servlet using <servlet-name> property